# ruby : how can I avoid hardcoding the classes names?

Tags: ruby, instance-variables, class-variables

I'm learning Ruby and the difference between class variables & instance variables.

I'm working on a piece of code where I have (a lot of) classes inheriting other classes.

```
class childImporter < parentImporter

  def self.infos
    parentImporter.infos.merge({
      :name=>           'My Importer',
    })
  end

  def self.schema
    schema = parentImporter.schema.deep_merge({
      'selectors' => {
        'track' => {
          'artist'=>  {'path'=>{'default'=>'//creator'}},
          'title'=>   {'path'=>{'default'=>['//name'}},
        }
      }
    })

    @@schema = schema
  end


  def initialize(params = {})
    super(params,childImporter.schema)
  end

end
```

I have two class variables: **infos** (importer informations) and **schema** (json schema).

I need them to be able to get them outside an instance (that is why they are class variables), and to be an extension of their parent value (that is why I *deep_merge* them), and

My example actually works, but I wonder if there is a way not to hardcode the classes names childImporter and parentImporter and rather use a reference to the parent class, for example having

> schema = PARENTCLASS.schema.deep_merge({

instead of

> schema = *parentImporter*.schema.deep_merge({

or

> super(params,THISCLASS.schema)

instead of

> super(params,*childImporter*.schema).

Is there a way to achieve this ?

Currently, if I try

> super(params,@@schema)

I get

> NameError: uninitialized class variable @@schema in childImporter

Thanks

Comment: Class names in Ruby must start with an uppercase letter. And there's a syntax error in your `{'default'=>['//name'}`. Aside from that you might want to turn your code into a [mcve] so that we can actually run it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I wonder if there is a way not to hardcode the classes names childImporter and parentImporter and rather use a reference to the parent class, for example having
>
> ```
> schema = PARENTCLASS.schema.deep_merge({
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> schema = parentImporter.schema.deep_merge({
> ```

The method you are looking for is [`superclass`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Class.html#method-i-superclass) – it returns the receiver's parent class. From within a class body or class method, you can call it without an explicit receiver:

```
class ParentImporter
  def self.infos
    { name: 'Parent Importer', type: 'Importer' }
  end
end

class ChildImporter < ParentImporter
  def self.infos
    superclass.infos.merge(name: 'Child Importer')
  end
end

ParentImporter.infos #=> {:name=>"Parent Importer", :type=>"Importer"}
ChildImporter.infos  #=> {:name=>"Child Importer", :type=>"Importer"}
```

But there's an even easier way. Classes [inherit](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/doc/syntax/modules_and_classes_rdoc.html#label-Inheritance) both, the class methods and the instance methods from their parent class. And in both variants, you can simply call `super` to invoke the parent's implementation:

```
class ChildImporter < ParentImporter
  def self.infos
    super.merge(name: 'Child Importer')
  end
end

ParentImporter.infos #=> {:name=>"Parent Importer", :type=>"Importer"}
ChildImporter.infos  #=> {:name=>"Child Importer", :type=>"Importer"}
```

In addition, you might want to [memoize](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the values so they are not re-created every time the methods are called:

```
class ParentImporter
  def self.infos
    @infos ||= { name: 'Parent Importer', type: 'Importer' }
  end
end

class ChildImporter < ParentImporter
  def self.infos
    @infos ||= super.merge(name: 'Child Importer')
  end
end
```

Those `@infos` are so-called *class instance variables*, i.e. instance variables in the scope of the class object(s). They behave exactly like instance variables in casual instances. In particular, there's no connection between the `@infos` in `ParentImporter` and the one in `ChildImporter`.

---

> or
>
> ```
> super(params,THISCLASS.schema)
> ```
>
> instead of
>
> ```
> super(params,childImporter.schema).
> ```

To get an object's class, you can call its [`class`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Object.html#method-i-class) method:

```
importer = ChildImporter.new

importer.class       #=> ChildImporter
importer.class.infos #=> {:name=>"Child Importer", :type=>"Importer"}
```

The same works from within an instance method:

```
  def initialize(params = {})
    super(params, self.class.schema)
  end
```

Note that the `class` method must always be called with an explicit receiver. Omitting the receiver and just writing `class.schema` results in an error.

---

Bottom note: I wouldn't use `@@` class variables at all. Just call your class methods.

Answer (score 0):

This may help - you can access class and superclass like this:

```
 class Parent
    
 end
    
 class Child < Parent
    
   def self.print_classes
     p itself
     p superclass
   end
  end
    
 Child.print_classes
```

This will print

> Child
>
> Parent